# Use input tag value from external html file for submitting

Tags: file, input, submit, external

I have got 2 html files:
File1.html contains a form to submit to a PHP file:

```
<form action="handle_form.php" method="get">
</form>
```

File2.html contains some input tags:

```
<input name="fullname" />
<input name="email" />
...
```

How can i load file2.html to file1.html to submit input value from file2.html to handle_form using PHP.Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use PHP, so your first file will be named file1.php and will contain:

```
<form action="handle_form.php" method="get">
    <?php
        include("file2.php");
    ?>
</form>
```

PHP files can contains only html tags and no PHP scripts, so feel free to use them.

Comment: If i only get content of body,how can do that.I mean.file2.html is a complete html file and i only want to get some content of any div tags inside it.

Comment: Your question has been asked in other thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753582/ssi-only-include-part-of-file so the only solution is to split file2.html in 2 parts, one will have the entire html part without the input tags and the other one will contain the input tags